How do I write a test with the FastAPI framework which uses a fake implementation of some object which itself must exist for the lifespan of the app?
I am trying to write some FastAPI tests.
To be more specific, I am trying to write tests which tests the FastAPI endpoints which I have defined. (In the FastAPI docs endpoints are refered to as "paths".)
The endpoints which I have defined call an object. This object ("service") maintains, in memory, all data related to the application.
This design imposes some requirements. Either threads must not be used or some mechanism such as locks must be used to enforce mutual exclusion. I opted for the former, to make things simple:

The "service" must be accessed synchronously, which implies the endpoints must be async def. This ensures that a thread pool is not used.
await is not called anywhere. This has the effect of causing each async endpoint to behave in a synchronous manner.

I have written a MWE for demonstration purposes. Here is the file containing my "FastAPI related code" including definitions of the endpoints:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Request

from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from implementation import Implementation


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    async with AsyncClient(app=app) as client:
        implementation = Implementation()
        yield {'implementation': implementation}
        implementation.shutdown() # MUST be called!

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.post('/api/increment')
async def api_increment(
    request: Request,
):
    implementation: Implementation = request.state.implementation
    implementation.increment()
    return {}


@app.get('/api/get_value')
async def api_get_value(
    request: Request,
):
    implementation: Implementation = request.state.implementation
    value = implementation.get_value()
    return {
        'value': value,
    }

This conforms to the requirements I gave details of above. You can see that I have used the "lifespan" concept to ensure implementation persists for the lifespan of the application.
Implementation represents the "service". There are two implementations of Implementation, a "real" one and a "fake" one which should be used when running the tests. (I have not yet built a full strategy pattern to present a single interface for both types, but this could be done very easily.)
Here is the "real" implementation of the "service":
class Implementation():

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.current_value = 0
        self._initialized = True
        print(f'Implementation starts')

    def shutdown(self) -> None:
        '''
        A function which must be called to cleanup resources before exit
        '''
        self._initialized = False
        print(f'Implementation stops')

    def increment(self) -> None:
        '''
        In reality this would do something like read/write to a file, db etc
        '''
        self.current_value += 1

    def get_value(self) -> None:
        return self.current_value

And here is the "fake" implementation, which should be used in tests:
class ImplementationFake():

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(f'Implementation starts')

    def shutdown(self) -> None:
        '''
        A function which must be called to cleanup resources before exit
        (at least if the implementation being used is the real implementation
        - the fake implementation probably wouldn't do anything here)
        '''
        print(f'Implementation stops')

    def increment(self) -> None:
        pass

    def get_value(self) -> None:
        return 42

Finally, here is the file containing my test code:
import pytest

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from fastapi_webserver import app

def test_get_value():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        response = client.get('/api/get_value')
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.json() == {
            #'value': 0, # <- using REAL implementation
            'value': 42, # <- using FAKE implementation
        }

This test fails because the value 0 is returned by the "real" implementation. This would be fine for running in production, but not the expected behaviour when running the "service" from within a test code. The expected behaviour is the "fake" implementation returns the hardcoded value 42.
I understand that there are two relevant "ideas" relating to this question.

The concept of lifespan contexts
The concept of dependencies

My object must exist for the lifespan of the FastAPI application. This seems to suggest it has to be loaded using a lifespan context.
However, if I understand correctly, dependencies are usually expected to be handled with the Dependency concept. The Dependency concept can be used to switch between a real and fake implementation of some object for testing purposes.
I do not understand how to combine these two idea. Could someone explain how to do so?

If you don't want to mock dependencies like it was proposed here you can  mock the Implementation itself.
You will need to make the import if implementation relative:
import implementation

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    async with AsyncClient(app=app) as client:
        implementation = implementation.Implementation()
        yield {'implementation': implementation}
        implementation.shutdown() # MUST be called!

And it tests you will need replace the call to the real class with the fake one. I will do it using fixture, but you can do it directly in a test before with TestClient(app) as client.
import implementation

@pytest.fixture()
def mock_impementation():
    implementation.Implementation = ImplementationFake

You can also use mocker to achieve this, but I find the direct replacement clearer.
